# How get MTU in POSIX

Tags: mtu

What is POSIX function to get MTU Size value ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no generic POSIX function for that.
The best you can do is to invoke a `GET_MTU` / `SIOCGIFMTU` `ioctl` on the socket, but this is not in the POSIX standard. not supported by all POSIX.

Comment: In linux it is documented in netdevice(7): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html